# How to format a number into a specified length in nodejs

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, node.js

i have a value **12.3456789**,
and i need result like **12.34**.

I tried **toPrecision()** method and got following error.

```
Object 3.0 has no method 'toPrecision'
```

Tried code is,

```
var ERA = stat['stat_group']['earned_run_average']  
statsHash['earned_run_average'] = ERA.toPrecision(4);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For javascript you can try,

if ERA is of type string first convert it to number `ERA = 1 * ERA`, then

```
statsHash['earned_run_average'] = 1 * ERA.toFixed(2);
```

hope this helps.